# Elementor lightbox buttons behavior when pressed

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, lightbox, elementor

In Android, the lightbox shows (for a second) a semitransparent cyan bar at the left & right button when the respective button left & right is pressed. Does somebody know a way to manage or avoid this behavior? TIA,

Comment: I would recommend checking out the active or focus states in a web browser dev inspector, my guess is theres a sneaky class being applied

Comment: Nevermind. After a regular research, I already solved: The issue is an Elementor lightbox css non standard use. Documented  in  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-tap-highlight-color . Already setted as transparent and avoid the behavior. BTW, Thanks for your comment, @JDawwgy

Answer (score 0):

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-tap-highlight-color

```
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
```